# Time Analysis of cdr

Tags: lisp, racket, time-complexity

I am unable to find a time complexity analysis of `cdr`. Does it run in constant time or linear time? In case the answer depends on the implementation of lisp, suppose I am using Racket.

Comment: Clojure might be slightly different, but it is close to 'near constant' IIRC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thinking in terms of C, a lisp pair is simply a `struct` with two fields, `car` and `cdr`. The lisp functions `car` and `cdr` amount simply to C access each field.

Here's a peek into [part of Racket's `scheme.h`](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/racket/src/racket/include/scheme.h#L327-L343):

```
typedef struct Scheme_Simple_Object
{
  Scheme_Inclhash_Object iso;

  union
    {
      struct { mzchar *string_val; intptr_t tag_val; } char_str_val;
      struct { char *string_val; intptr_t tag_val; } byte_str_val;
      struct { void *ptr1, *ptr2; } two_ptr_val;
      struct { int int1; int int2; } two_int_val;
      struct { void *ptr; int pint; } ptr_int_val;
      struct { void *ptr; intptr_t pint; } ptr_long_val;
      struct { struct Scheme_Object *car, *cdr; } pair_val;
      struct { mzshort len; mzshort *vec; } svector_val;
      struct { void *val; Scheme_Object *type; } cptr_val;
    } u;
} Scheme_Simple_Object;
```

Note this part of the `union`:

```
      struct { struct Scheme_Object *car, *cdr; } pair_val;
```

And [later in `scheme.h`](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/racket/src/racket/include/scheme.h#L626-L627) you find:

```
#define SCHEME_CAR(obj)      (((Scheme_Simple_Object *)(obj))->u.pair_val.car)
#define SCHEME_CDR(obj)      (((Scheme_Simple_Object *)(obj))->u.pair_val.cdr)
```

Of course the Racket `cdr` function will do a tiny bit more work than this C macro, such as checking that it was given a `pair?`.

Answer (score 8):

`cdr` can be expected to take constant time in any Lisp. It's just a lookup of the second member in a `cons` cell.

Comment: It depends on your definition of Lisp. I think you can get a reasonable Lisp dialect without basing it on cons cells at all. My dialect has no `car`, `cdr` and has `first` and `rest` instead (but `rest` is not constant time because `lists` are first class objects similar to CL vectors)

Comment: @6502: for academic/homebrew variants of Lisp, it need indeed not be constant time. But in the implementations that I've inspected it is, and Lisp programmers tend to rely on it. Textbooks also implicitly assume it when describing the complexity of Lisp operations.

Answer (score 1):

Rackets [definition of a pair](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=car) talks of `car` and `cdr` as the pair accessors so indirectly it specifies it as O(1). To make it O(n) for `cdr` you'd have to reverse it making it `butlast` and that would not conform to the racket documentation.

Rackets mother language, Scheme, have a [R6RS spec](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-4.html#node_sec_Temp_11) where `car` and `cdr` are accessors to fields in a `pair` and also indirectly O(1).

In [Common Lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_c.htm#cons), a cuisine of Scheme, have similar description with the only difference that they use the name `cons` instead of `pair` in their specification. (you tagged lisp)

It's not strage though, since `cons`/`pairs` are an essential data type defined by [John McCarthy's LISP](http://paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html), the mother of all LISPs, and it's very first implementation had assembly instructions that retrieved something called [address and decrement from a memory location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR#Etymology) and the letters a and d in `car`/`cdr` are from that terminology.